# How to use `scipy.integrate.quad` to compute integral of a function which depends on the integral of another function

Tags: python, function, math, numerical-integration, quad

Any help to compute this integration, `F` function is defined using the `f` function which involves the first integration, finally, integrate `F`.

```py
from scipy.integrate import quad

f = lambda x,a : a**2*x

def F(s,a):
  return quad(f,0,s,args=(a,))
quad(F,0,5,args=(4,))
```

Got the error:

```py
      2 def F(s,a):
      3   return quad(f,0,s,args=(a,))
----> 4 quad(F,0,5,args=(4,))
      5 
    446     if points is None:
    447         if infbounds == 0:
--> 448             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    449         else:
    450             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: must be real number, not tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the return values of [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html):

> Returns:
>
> `y`: `float` The integral of func from a to b.
>
> `abserr`: `float` An estimate of the absolute error in the result.
>
> ...

So there are multiple return values (a tuple) and that's why you're getting the `TypeError: must be real number, not tuple` message.

I guess, you're just interested in the integral value `quad(...)[0]` so that's what your `F` should return:

```py
from scipy.integrate import quad

f = lambda x, a: a**2 * x
F = lambda x, a: quad(f, 0, x, args=(a,))[0]

I = quad(F, 0, 5, args=(4,))
print(I)
```

Which prints:

```
(333.33333333333337, 3.700743415417189e-12)
```

Comment: One more question, can you help?          from scipy.integrate import quad
from math import sqrt

f = lambda x, a: a**2 * x
F = lambda x, a: quad(f, 0, x, args=(a,))[0]
rho = 5
I = quad(sqrt(F(??)-F(rho,a)), 0, rho, args=(4,))
print(I)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at the problem is to realize that you're integrating the function `a**2 * y` over the triangle spanned by the points `[0, 0]`, `[5, 0]`, and `[5, 5]`. You could then use triangle quadrature from [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (one of my projects) to compute the value:

```py
import quadpy

a = 4.0


def g(x):
    return a ** 2 * x[1]


scheme = quadpy.triangle.dunavant_05()
val = scheme.integrate(g, [[0.0, 0.0], [5.0, 0.0], [5.0, 5.0]])
print(val)
```

This should require a much fewer function evaluations that the nested quad approach.